# fastest way too fill a rows that contain all zeros

Tags: python, numpy, row, zero

what is the fastest way to fill every row in 2d array that contains all zeros with different value.

Only the rows that all contain Zero..

the only idea I have is a loop and using np.all() to check every row

```
array([[2, 6, 9, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 8, 5, 4, 7]])

array([[2, 6, 9, 7, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 8, 5, 4, 7]])
```

Comment: How about ```array[~np.any(array, axis=1)] = new_value```?

Comment: thanks, post it like an answer so i can approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if this is sufficient:

```py
a = np.array([[2, 6, 9, 7, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [3, 8, 5, 4, 7]])

a[~a.any(axis=1)] = 1
```

Slight note: I use `~np.any(...)` instead of `np.all(a==0)` because the `a` array is larger than the boolean array returned by `all` or `any`. The `a==0` creates a 2D boolean array. Negating the 1D boolean array created by `any` requires less work and memory.

Comment: `a[(~a).any(1)] = 1`

Comment: @MadPhysicist You mean ```(~a).all(1)```, don't you? Using the member function instead of ```np.any``` is actually faster. But negating before checking is slower as I've explained. Just tested it

Comment: Of course. It's late and I need sleep :)

Comment: That being said, using `np.invert(a.any(1))` might be faster since it bypasses python's operator stuff, and `a.any(1).__invert__()` might be faster still.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Tested it with timeit. Honestly, seeing how ```a.any``` is faster than ```np.any(a)```, I would have guessed that ```np.invert``` would be slower but it has practically the same performance. Using ```__invert__``` is actually a bit slower for some reason.

Comment: These are tests you want to run with very small arrays, since you're specifically comparing the overhead

Comment: @MadPhysicist Tested with 100x100 and 10x10. Same result

Comment: Try `(2,)` or a scalar if you want to see the deltas over the noise. The differences, if there are any, will be miniscule

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, no. If it is not visible in a 10x10 matrix, it is not worth entertaining. Switching from ```np.any``` to ```a.any``` has been worth it since it is shorter and faster. ```np.invert``` and circumventing the operator have been consistently slower and more verbose

Comment: Agreed. The overhead is a constant, not a proportion.